# What is the meaning of "Ask whose invitation I've got"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here Brendan calls Laura for Halloween invitation.

> Laura: Who is this? Or I'll hang up.
>
> Brendan: You don't know me. I'll save you some time.
>
> Laura: I know everyone, and I have all the time in the world.
>
> Brendan: Folly of youth. **Ask whose invitation I've got**.
>
> Laura: What you said...
>
> Brendan: Emily Kostich.

This lines are from Brick (2005) mystery movie.

Is he saying: "he got invitation & asking her"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As P.E. Dant mentions in his comment, the phrase is just a colloquial variation on "Ask me whose invitation I **have**".  But let's break it down.

In English, the verb "to get" is used in a wide variety of ways, often with subtle differences.  For example:

> "I **got** $100" = I *received* $100.
>   "I **have got** $100" = I *possess* (or I *am holding*) $100

Note the difference -- I *receive* vs. I *have* something.  It would not be redundant to say that I *get* something, and then *I've got* it.  Some other examples:

> I **got** your invitation.
>   **I've got** your invitation.
>
> Whose invitation **did I get**?
>   Whose invitation **have I got**?

In the movie, Brendan is not saying he *received* the invitation.  He's saying that he *has* the invitation, and possibly that he's actually *holding* the invitation at that moment.

The second structure, "Ask X if Y" is an alternate way to phrase a question as a kind of *imperative*

> **Do you want to know** if I like chocolate?
>   **Ask me** if I like chocolate.
>
> **Does** she like chocolate?
>   **Ask her** if she likes chocolate.

You will generally use this structure to imply that you already know the answer -- that it's a [rhetorical question](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rhetorical%20question) -- but you want the person to ask anyway:

> A: **Ask me** if I love you.
>   B: Do you love me?
>   A: Yes, of course! I love you more than pizza, and that's saying something.

Put the pieces together, and you have Brendan telling Laura that he *has* an invitation from someone, and he thinks she will want to know about it, so he *tells her* to *ask* him about it.

As a side note:  The movie *Brick* is in a style known as *["hard-boiled detective fiction"](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HardboiledDetective)*, with the twist that it's set in a high school with teenagers as the main characters.  If the dialogue seems oddly *adult* for such young people, it's because *high school students do not normally talk this way* -- the setting is a deliberate choice by the filmmaker to add a [*surreal*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/surreal) element to the movie.

Comment: Actually, nobody in real life, high-school or not, talks the way characters talk in hard-boiled detective fiction, any more than people in real life break out spontaneous but well-choreographed original song-and-dance numbers, the way they do in Broadway musicals.  It's just a convention of the genre.